# $R$ -module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules. Suppose there exists $R$-module homomorphism $\phi:M \to N$ and $\psi:N \to M$ such that $(\psi \ \circ \ \phi)(m) =m, \forall m \in M. $ Could anyone advise me on how to prove $N \subseteq \text{ker}(\psi) \oplus \phi(M) \ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $N$ can be embedded in $ \text{ker}(\psi) \oplus \phi(M) \ ?$ instead of $N \subseteq \text{ker}(\psi) \oplus \phi(M) \ ?$

Comment: No, I mean what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: write $n= \left(n-\phi \circ \psi \left(n\right) \right) + \phi \circ \psi \left(n\right)$

Comment: Thank you. I have solved it. I was thinking if it is necessary that  $\phi$ or $\psi$ is injective and/surjective...

Comment: Since you assume $\psi \circ \phi = id$, then it follows $\phi$ is injective and $\psi$ is surjective.